# Acegi pligin not enabling HTTPS with 'forceHttps' param

Tags: https, spring-security

I am working on an old application which has huge code from legacy.

Application is based on Spring 2.0 and using Acegi plugin for security. The Tomcat server is successfully configured on HTTPS port.

Now I need to redirect the login over HTTPS. I tries setting following in my template_spring_config.xml

```
<bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class="src.auth.acegi.myAuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginFormUrl" value="http://@domain.name@/welcome"/>
    <property name="forceHttps" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Help found so far indicates that this much should be enough to redirect on HTTPS. But this is not working at all and my Request for login remains on HTTP.

I cannot switch to  Spring-Security and higher Spring versions due to time constraint. 
Please help if you know what else I need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to say for sure since you are using a custom entry point implementation (which may behave differently), but you are using an absolute URL, which will probably override the default logic for building the redirect. Try using `https://` rather than `http://` for your login URL scheme.

Note that you really shouldn't be using Acegi since development stopped on it a long time ago. It contains most (possibly all) of the vulnerabilities that have subsequently been patched in Spring Security. The same goes for Spring itself.

Comment: Thanks got the reply. Yes I understand that moving to Spring-Security would be right thing to do. Just that situations are not allowing me to do the switch. Let me try it once and I will get back to you.